# nginx config variable names with special characters

Tags: nginx

This is primarily in relation to the $arg_NAME and $cookie_NAME variables.

I couldn't find much documentation on the syntax of variables in nginx.
What characters can variable names contain, and are there any requirements to escape them?

For example, how would I get the value of the cookie `group[key]`?
`$cookie_group[key]` doesn't seem to work for me, presumably because `[]` are considered special characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out a while ago, and thought that I should update this for anyone else who stumbles across this.

http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?11,241016,241069#msg-241069

Basically a patch (available at above link) needs to be applied for something like a `group[key]` cookie to work.

Comment: i think it would be better if you add '...So I went through the source code and it appears that anything other than a letter, number or underscore is explicitly disallowed in variable names....' in your answer